# Как правильно настроить SQL Server на Windows Server 2012 R2 для полноценной работы с IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, iis, windows-server

Здравствуйте.

Никогда раньше с этим не сталкивался — работал все время с MongoDB. С MS-SQL только локально, и то в игрушечных проектах. Собственно, вопрос:

Как настроить SQL Server на Windows Server 2012 R2 таким образом, чтобы приложение ASP.NET MVC, запущенное на IIS 8.5, получал полноценный доступ к нему?

В данном случае даже просто приложение (с Identity 2.0) не работает с базой, ругаясь на базу: то ошибки вылетают, то третье другое, то прав нету. Перерыл весь StackOverFlow, русскоязычные форумы — не нашел материала разжеванного, на простых примерах. Пожалуйста, кому не сложно — объясните.

Comment: @maximka, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

[Обычная установка](http://tavalik.ru/ustanovka-microsoft-sql-server-2012/), единственная проблема с параметрами ISS может быть, так как описания нормального я не встречал. В принципе по шагам:

- устанавливаем .net framework;
- устанавливаем asp.net mvc framework;
- подключаем сервер и компоненты IIS (всякие функции HTTP, ASP.NET, MVC, ISAPI, etc по необходимости нужного);
- устанавливаем mssql server;
- в configuration manager выставляем протокол ip включенным и выставляем ip адреса активными.

**Обновление**

А через SQL Server Management Studio соединяется? Это самый простой способ проверить саму базу на работоспособность, иначе может быть что-то в настройках самого веб-сервера не так.

Comment: @Alex Krass , я сам SQL Server так же устанавливал, если не ошибаюсь. Все равно не могу соединиться с ним из ASP.NET MVC через IIS. :(

Comment: @Alex Krass, через Management Studio соединяется, базы могу создавать или открывать свои .mdf-файлы. Вот, я тоже думаю, что в IIS проблема. Понятия не имею, как их настроить и подружить. С MongoDB все намного проще было.